# Drupal 6 to 7 update error

Tags: ajax, drupal-6

I'm upgrading from Drupal 6 to 7, but after clicking 'Continue' [here](http://www.domain.com/update.php?op=info):  I get the following:

**139 pending updates**

Then I click 'Apply pending updates', it starts updating, then I get the following error:

**An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. [Path](http://www.domain.com/update.php?op=selection&token=PExs9Sy1n9SDNAurL_SBEnnsUMlKtlRW2AuzP_UkT88&id=11653&op=do):  StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_type_cache_reset() in /home/domain/public_html/modules/node/node.install on line 578**

Any thoughts/ideas what this is?

Answer (score 1):

go to system table search for node module and update its status to 1, This is happening because node module is not enabled and the function node_type_cache_reset() is written in that module , since node module is unpublished it is unable to call the function written in this module.